# Is there any process to export the cell color from primefaces dataTable to Excel

Tags: jsf, primefaces

it is required to export the primefaces dataTable values to a excel with the background colour of each value.

Answer (score 1):

There's no autommatic way to achieve your goal.
You should use a `dataExporter` with a postprocessor:

```
<p:dataExporter type="xls"
                target="p-datatable-id"
                fileName="result-filename"
                postProcessor="#{bean.method}"
                />
```

This processor will receive an HSSFWorkbook (or XSSFWorkbook if you use XLSX) after exporting data, so you can modify it to suit your needs.

You can view an example in: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/dataexporter/customizedDocuments.xhtml